# BIOS Version from x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, bios

Is there a way I can find the version and other information of BIOS using x86 assembly in DosBOX?

Answer (score 4):

To get BIOS information, use the int 15h, AH = C0h call. For example:

```
mov ah, C0h
int 15h
;Use info here
```

[Here](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/docs/interrupts/int-html/rb-1594.htm)'s some docs on the table format.

Answer (score 3):

In dosbox you'll have access to the emulated bios only. If you need information about the real hardware, use some OS-dependent way. On linux you can use the program `dmidecode` for example. It gathers information by reading the BIOS through `/dev/mem`, among other ways.